# How can I make the background color the same as the x-height of text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have place a heading title inside a div container, you can see there are extra spaces, at the top and bottom, and I would like to remove those extra spaces.

[image: Issue - screenshot]

My goal is this:

[image: trying to achieve - screenshot]

I want the 'x-height' of the text to be aligned and touch the container top, and the text baseline to be aligned to the container bottom, like my screenshot above.

I've tried updating the line-height, but doesn't seem to work exactly. This is what I can getting:

[image: Adjusting the line-height (screenshot)]

I am constantly changing the line-height value and I can't get it to look how I would like.

Is there a way to achieve this by CSS or JS?

I want it responsive too. If we resize the browser or if the font-size starts to shrink or grow, it should stay like that.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.title {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: clamp(7rem, 4.500000001rem + .0833333333 * 100vw, 12rem);
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0.5;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.o-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  ;
  background-color: coral;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="o-container">
  <h1 class="title">Choosing type</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Azu I did set the padding and margin to 0

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, nice question. My solution uses an absolutely positioned pseudo-element for the background, with its `height` set to `1ex`, which is the **x-height** of the current font. You then just need to experiment to find the appropriate `top` value, which will be different for each font, but is typically between 30% and 40%.

[image: four examples of the solution in use, with different fonts]

Note that this will only work if your text is displayed in a single line. As soon as the text wraps (on a mobile, for example), the solution will break. But if you can prevent wrapping by setting `white-space: nowrap;` or adjusting your font size on mobile, it might be workable.

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.title {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1ex;
  background-color: coral;
  z-index: -1;
}
.t1 {
  font-family: serif;
}
.t1::before {
  top: 38%;
}
.t2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.t2::before {
  top: 33%;
}
.t3 {
  font-family: cursive;
}
.t3::before {
  top: 41%;
}
.t4 {
  font-family: monospace;
}
.t4::before {
  top: 39%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title t1">Choosing type</h1>
<h1 class="title t2">Choosing type</h1>
<h1 class="title t3">Choosing type</h1>
<h1 class="title t4">Choosing type</h1>
```